# Object-c/iOS :Program urns fine on simulator but got "SIGABRT" when install to device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, sigabrt

I gor a strange problem ,My application runs normal on simulator

But when I try to install it to my ipod

I got program receive "SIGABRT"

My code is too big ,I'm not sure where the bug is...

How can I fix it ???

Many thanks ...

I feel so helpless...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you checking the crash logs on the device itself? (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in Xcode from memory.)

Also, are you doing large amounts of processing on start-up? (I know that iOS will terminate applications that don't finishing launching within a certain time period.)

Irrespective, without more information on the specific error, there's not a lot else to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with the debugger, you can check the console after the crash for what crashed!

Comment: No, I think he means the console. The thing that shows up with command+shift+r — where all your NSLogs go. When an app crashes, it'll also show the nature of the problem and give a quick stack backtrace.